# chatbot for my customer service representatives

Tags: javascript, node.js, artificial-intelligence, full-text-search, chatbot

I am interested in building a chatbot for my customer service representatives. A type of chat where they can ask technical questions and the chat will answer them according to the data I put into it. The data is manuals with information on how to perform technical operations in the company.
Is there a service where I can store the information in order to build a chat of this type?
The information I have is now in information guides that I will have to turn you into data that will be a governor for the system, how can this be done?
chatbot for my customer service representatives

If you have more ideas for development, I would greatly appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

This is something I’ve been wanting to explore as well for my company, so maybe we discover something good together.

So far, what I have considered:

- Use a [Hubot](https://hubot.github.com/docs/) with custom scripts hooked to our knowledge base/help center. It integrates well with Slack which we already use in the company, so it can help reduce context switching when asking questions and be used by other teams beyond customer support. There is a lot of community content to guide you and it’s free to use!
- Depending on where you have your knowledge stored and what platforms you use, you may even be able to build some simple integrations that help your team members search for answers right where they work. For example, Zendesk has a lot of integrations, many plug into the knowledge base service and can be used right in the ticket interface to offer solutions to customers that the customers can then use to mark the ticket as solved themselves (look for [Knowledge Capture in Zendesk](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/4408823923610-Searching-and-linking-articles-using-the-Knowledge-Capture-app)), they also have a chatbot. You could even do something seemingly wild like hooking your knowledge or a spreadsheet of keywords mapped to answers to a [Zapier zap](https://zapier.com/) or similar automation that touches Slack or some other comms channel.

Of course, you also have your subscription services which are probably easier to setup since they may abstract most of the implementation details, but there are so many of those and I just don’t find it interesting to pay for something that I could build with some simple automations to POC first. You can always find those services online though.

My recommendation, from having build some automation already, is to keep it simple and build the simplest working MVP you can to test if it will be helpful and discover what you don’t yet know about your company and employees, then you can use all that knowledge to build a better one or improve upon it if you decide to follow through.

There are also a lo of resources online that can help you understand how others have fared in similar projects, I found this article that seems interesting: [Top 8 considerations for building an internal chatbot to increase employee engagement and answer employee questions](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/top-8-considerations-building-internal-chatbot-increase-kristina-tool)

I’m also at the research stages here, so if you find something good, feel free to share it!-

Also, I’d like to share this quote from that article above:

> A chatbot’s benefits go beyond cost reduction, they are also a tool used to increase job satisfaction, by freeing up employees from repetitive tasks and allowing more time for creative work: A PWC study noted that 34% of executives say the time they freed up using chatbots allows them to focus on deep thinking and creating.

Take note of this, a chatbot and any other form of automation should not only reduce costs but free your employees to tackle better problems and grow with you. Help them see this and encourage them to contribute with more valuable input, I assure you most people have it in there to do greater things, and as an employer you have the unique opportunity to influence people positively every day. Stay awesome!